# Simulate Is not working without state in react js

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

This is my functional Component.

```
const InputText = (props: Props) => {
 return (
  <div>
  <StyledInput type="text" placeholder={props.placeholder} />
  <br></br>
   </div>
   );
  };
 export default InputText;

and this is my test cases.
enter code here
  const wrap = (props: Props) => shallow(<InputText {...props} />);
  it("input text change", () => {
// const wrap = (props: Props) => mount(<StyledInput {...props} />);
  const wrapper = wrap({ placeholder: "UserName" });
  const usernameInput = wrapper.find("input");
  usernameInput.simulate("change", { target: { value: "umesh@hcl.com" } });
  expect(usernameInput.text()).toEqual("umesh@hcl.com");
});
```

So this test case failed with error:

> Expected "Umesh@hcl.com" and recevide:"";

How can I resolve this?

Comment: are you doing mount or shallow, i see the code is commented out in the question

Comment: i think you the simulate is not working and i see the input field as an uncontrolled component,

Comment: const wrap = (props: Props) => shallow(<InputText {...props} />);

Comment: posted the answer, kindly check it !! happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one

App.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow, configure } from "enzyme";
import Input from "./App";
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});


describe("Input Component", () => {
  it("should trigger the onchange", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Input />);
    wrapper
      .find("input")
      .simulate("change", { target: { value: "on typing" } });
      expect(wrapper.find('input').props().value).toBe('on typing')
  });
});
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const InputText = props => {
  const [inputText, setInput] = useState("");

  const onHandleChange = e => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputText}
        onChange={onHandleChange}
      />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputText;
```

Comment: i don't want to use state.

Comment: i dont think so for an uncontrolled component it will work !!, you need to make it as a controlled component.

Comment: Cool, If you find any related article for uncontrolled component with enzyme add to this answer so it will be helpful for future reference  happy coding:)